# Magento code need precision

Tags: php, magento

I'm currently checking a Magento extension and I have a slight doubt about a piece of code. I would like you to explain. I understand all of it but not this one :

```
$customerID == " "
```

Is there a case where Magento have a customer id like that ( a space?) ?
Thanks a lot for your reply !
Here the entire function.

```
public function isAvailable(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{

    $event           = $observer->getEvent();
    $method          = $event->getMethodInstance(); //$method return the payment method
    $result          = $event->getResult();         //$result return true if method is active
    $quote           = $event->getQuote();          //$quote return var from cart
    if($method->getCode() == 'custompayment' ){
        //$customerGroup        = $quote->getCustomerGroupId();
        // $customerGroup="";
        // $customerID="";
         $login = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' )->isLoggedIn(); //Check if User is Logged In
    if($login)
    {
        $customerGroup = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(); //Get Customers Group ID
        $customerID = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId(); //Get Customers ID

    }
        $selectedCustomerGroups =   Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/custompayment/specificcustomers');
        $selectedCustomerGroupsArray = explode(",", $selectedCustomerGroups);
            if($selectedCustomerGroups != "" || $customerID == " "){
                if(!in_array($customerGroup, $selectedCustomerGroupsArray)) {
                            $result->isAvailable = false;
                    } 

            }
            else{
               if($result->isAvailable==1){
                    $result->isAvailable = true;
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: As far as I know there is not, but you can take a look on the table 'customer_entity' and check whether you have an space id.

Comment: My guess would be they want to test if $customerID is empty and put a space by mistake

Comment: Okay. I think it is both true. The "customer_entity" doesn't show any space. Thank you both of you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by adrien54 and JokiRuiz.